# How to calculate this derivate using the chain rule

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

How can we get this result, step by step

$$\frac{d(\frac{f(k_t)}{k_t})}{dt}= \frac{\dot{k_t}}{k_t}(f'(k_t)-\frac{f(k_t)}{k_t})$$

Comment: Hint: Use the quotient rule (or product rule) for derivatives.

Comment: @kccu Sure. But how can you proceed from here onwards from here?

$$\frac{d(\frac{f(k_t)}{k_t})}{dt}= f(k_t) *\frac{d(\frac{1}{k_t})}{dt}+\frac{1}{k_t}*\frac{df(k_t)}{dt} $$

Comment: Now use the chain rule to compute the derivative of $\frac{1}{k_t}$ with respect to $t$, and the derivative of $f(k_t)$ with respect to $t$. The former is the composition of the functions $\frac{1}{x}$ and $k_t$, while the latter is the composition of the functions $f(x)$ and $k_t$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{f}{k}\stackrel{\stackrel{\text{Chain}}{\text{rule}}}{=}\dot{k}\frac{d}{dk}\frac{f}{k}\stackrel{\stackrel{\text{Product}}{\text{rule}}}{=}\dot{k}\left(\frac{f^\prime}{k}-\frac{f}{k^2}\right)=\frac{\dot{k}}{k}\left(f^\prime-\frac{f}{k}\right).$$